# JQuery .attr() not adding any attributes but "src"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm practicing JQuery and I wanted to create some images from JSON data.

I'm using element.attr(attr,value) and it's working nicely with the *src* attribute but no matter what I can't add any other attributes to my *img* tag and I don't know why. You can see that I'm trying to add one *id* but it doesn't work.

Here is my JS code :

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.5.1/data/en_US/champion.json",
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
data: {},
success: function(response){
    var i = 1;
    $.each(response.data, function (champion, infos) {
        $.each(infos, function (infoKey, infoValue) {
            var image = $("<img class='champion-icon'>");
            if(infoKey == "id"){
                image.attr('id', infoValue);
            }
            if(infoKey == "image"){
                image.attr('src', "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.5.1/img/champion/" + infoValue['full']);
                image.appendTo("#champions");
                if(i == 14){
                    $("<br>").appendTo("#champions");
                    i = 0;
                }
                i++;
            }
        });
    })
}
```

});

Comment: If `infoKey` is "id", your code *does* add the "id" attribute. However, it then moves on to the next element of the "infos" list without doing anything with the created image element.

Comment: I added a variable, filling it in my first if and console.log it in my second, i do have what i want but it isn't adding it into my image

Comment: You're creating a new image on each element in the "infos" list, but you only add it to the page when you see the key "image".

Comment: @Pointy Is right: If `infoKey` is `id`, then you add an id to `image` and you move on without appending `image` to `#champions`. What exactly do you want your code to do?

Comment: You shouldn't be iterating the `infos` object to get its properties. Drop the inner loop, create the image, and use `infos.id` and `infos.image` to add the attributes.

Comment: I actually do have <img class='...' src='...'/> but i want to add an id, i even tried to image.attr('src', ...); then image.attr('id', id ); console.log(id) i my log gave me what i want but the id wasn't added

Comment: You're not grasping what others are telling you. Look at your code. You're only doing an `.appendTo()` of an image when the property is `"image"`. Let's say a single `infos` has 20 properties. You're creating a new image *for every single property*, yet only appending the one that gets created when the property is `"image"`, which is also when the `src` is set. That's why the appended image only has `src` and the initial class you embedded in the HTML.

Comment: As I stated above, get rid of the inner loop, and access the properties from the current champion directly. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qf51kys0/

Comment: oh ok i see, sorry i feel so stupid right now... thanks

Comment: Is your problem solved or do you still have doubts?